# What is this black line in my rendered donut?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

[image: this is the image of the problem]

What is this black line in my rendered view? 
Also, I think there's a problem in my 3d view.
There are also some lines in my object I can't explain.  I have tried to change the scale and modifiers, but nothing works.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Well you can clearly see the line already in the left image

Comment: Check for overlapping geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like You are following the tutorial for beginners made by BlenderGuru aka Andrew Price, Hassan, right? If I remember it right he duplicates the top half of the donut and make it bigger and then use proportional falloff to make that random chocolate edge.

Because of duplication of a top half part of a donut there is a big chance of overlapping vertices so to solve this, please **select the donut (complete one) and go to EditMode and DEACTIVATE the "Limit selection to visible"** (bottom green circle on the image) to make the hidden vertices visible. Once done please **select the top vertices with the <kbd>B</kbd> key (WITHOUT the middle ones - marked RED) and delete them with the <kbd>X</kbd> key choosing VERTICES** as shown on the picture - done!

The vertices which needs to be deleted are selected below ... You dont need that top part of a donut anymore cause You have the chocolate object instead now ;). Hope it helps buddy.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot man this helped me a lot and the problem has been fixed , also your information makes me avoid future mistakes , thanks man :)

Comment: You are quite welcome Hassan! :)